# subquery to bring all previous records

Tags: sql, subquery

```
SELECT        TOP (100) PERCENT yy, mm, Item, SUM(Qty) AS qty, COALESCE
                             ((SELECT        SUM(Qty) AS Expr1
                                 FROM            dbo.v_Storage AS p
                                 WHERE        (Item = i.Item) AND (mm < i.mm) AND (yy = i.yy)), 0) AS OpnQty
FROM            dbo.v_Storage AS i
GROUP BY yy, mm, Item
ORDER BY yy, mm, Item
```

It brings this:

[image].

but it is missing to bring the highlighted item because the qty is zero for mm=3. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you need all combinations of years, months, and items, then you need to generate those combinations and then bring in the data.  The rest is done in a similar way:

```
select yy.yy, mm.mm, i.Item,
       sum(s.qty) as qty,
       ifnull((SELECT SUM(Qty)
               FROM dbo.v_Storage s2
               WHERE (s2.Item = i.Item) AND (s2.mm < mm.mm) AND (s2.yy = yy.yy)
              ), 0) AS OpnQty
from (select distinct yy from v_Storage) yy cross join
     (select distinct mm from v_Storage) mm cross join
     (select distinct item from v_Storage) i left outer join
     v_Storage s
     on s.yy = yy.yy and s.mm = mm.mm and s.item = i.item
group by yy.yy, mm.mm, i.item
order by yy.yy, mm.mm, i.item;
```

Note that I replaced `coalesce()` is `ifnull()`.  In this situation, `ifnull()` is faster, because `coalesce()` will execute the subquery twice.

If you are using SQL Server 2012, you can replace the whole subquery with a cumulative sum:

```
select yy.yy, mm.mm, i.Item,
       sum(s.qty) as qty,
       coalesce(sum(s.qty), 0) over (partition by i.item, yy.yy order by mm.mm) as OpnQty
from (select distinct yy from v_Storage) yy cross join
     (select distinct mm from v_Storage) mm cross join
     (select distinct item from v_Storage) i left outer join
     v_Storage s
     on s.yy = yy.yy and s.mm = mm.mm and s.item = i.item
group by yy.yy, mm.mm, i.item
order by yy.yy, mm.mm, i.item;
```